# Usage of “mettre” with direct and indirect object

Tags: usage, pronoms, verbes

Am I right in thinking that the verb *mettre* can take both direct and indirect object. I looked it up in all the dictionaries I know of, but I couldn't find any examples where it is used with an indirect object.

However, I have this sentence (It's from a Youtube video):

> je ***vous*** mets en bas l’info

To my logic, *vous* is the indirect object denoting the recipient and *l'info* is the direct object, thus the sentence should mean something like: “I (am going to?) put the information ***for you*** below.” (I'm not sure why the original sentence is in the present, though.)

Or maybe I misunderstood the sentence completely, because I'm a real newbie to French.

Comment: Some other examples showing both direct and indirect objects: _Je mets ma montre à mon poignet gauche_ (I put my watch on my left wrist); _[Peter Sagan met la main aux fesses d'une hôtesse](http://www.sudinfo.be/695513/article/sports/cyclisme/2013-04-02/peter-sagan-met-la-main-aux-fesses-d-une-hotesse-et-si-ce-n-etait-pas-la-premier)_ (Peter Sagan puts his hand on a podium girl's behind)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this is correct, here *mettre* is used with an indirect object *vous* and with a direct object *l'info*. The use of *vous* directly as a pronoun is slightly informal though, as the correct preposition would be **pour**:

> Je mets en bas l'info pour vous.

In comparison “*Je vous vérifie ça*” is slightly colloquial, and one would expect “*Je vérifie cela pour vous*” in a very formal discourse. In particular, *mettre l'info à vous* is clearly not idiomatic. In other situations “*mettre quelque chose à quelqu'un*” could easily be misinterpreted.

As for the tense, it's perfectly usual in French to use present in this case. *J'ai mis*, *Je vais mettre* or *Je mettrai* are also possible.

Comment: Thanks! Do you sometimes use the present simple to talk about the future?

Comment: Hum, I assumed the info was simultaneously shown at the bottom. But in fact, it's often possible to use the present to express events planned for the future (Example: *Ce soir je vais au cinéma*.); you should rather check whether is it is unambiguous beforehand though.

Comment: I'm far from sure that this _vous_ is an indirect object.  It looks like another construction to me, quite familiar and possible with any verb.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Mmm, now you might be right. The same colloquial use of a pronoun as in “Je *te* vérifie ça”? But, I guess this kind of usage is outside the scope of standard grammatical analysis. Maybe *apostrophe pronoun* would be a good name for this?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, I'll try to look if Grevisse says something about it this evening.

Comment: *vous* is definitely an indirect object: *à qui ?* is the question that is answered with the indirect object: *je mets l'info* -> *à qui ?* -> *à vous*. But I disagree with the informality of the sentence. It is just not polite as referred to the *vous* but saying *je te mets ton manteau en bas* (I put your coat downstairs) is totally correct.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of searching on the Net would have revealed many examples of the indirect object personal pronoun with *mettre*. What throws people off is the fact that ‘*mettre à*’ with persons is quite rare. (Of course, there is ‘*remettre à*’ but that's a different verb.)

Instead of looking for the equivalent of the verb + *à*, you must look for a beneficiary of the action or the *pronom bénéfactif*. By far, the most common form is *lui + mettre*. A couple of examples are:

- *Je lui mets son manteau.*
- *Ça lui met l'eau à la bouche.*

Comment: C'est indéniable. Mais ce n'est pas la même utilisation que dans l'exemple. Il faut le préciser.

Answer (score 1):

Well the sentence could actually mean two things depending on what was in the author's head when he wrote it.

- *Je vous **ai mis** l'info en bas.* (I have put the info below.)
- *Je vous **mettrai** l'info en bas.* (I will put the info below.)

The present tense might sound weird, but it's correct. You could say it while talking, but not while writing a letter(as an example).

Also, the author inverted *l'info* and *en bas*. That do sound weird and would sound better written like I wrote it in the two examples above.

Your interpretation of the sentence is correct.

---

Note that in the sentence *vous* is a “*complément d'objet indirect*”. Because it answers a question that has an *à* in it. *Je mets **à qui**?* → *à vous*.

Comment: The question is clearly *pour qui*, not *à qui*. Nobody would say *Je mets l'info en bas à Pierre*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Well the "à + qui/quoi" question is just a way of saying it to find the "complément d'objet indirect". It's just a trick. That's why it sounds weird.

Comment: A trick that doesn't explain anything to someone who is not already familiar with the French language…

Answer (score 1):

In

> Je vous mets l'info en bas.

It's a case where we are using the indirect object conjoin forms of pronoun but not as an indirect object but as an adverbial complement.

Grevisse, *le bon Usage*:

> Elles correspondent à des compléments nominaux précédés d'une autre préposition que *à*. (Dans ce cas, les grammairiens français parlent souvent de complément d'attribution [et Grevisse ailleurs appelle ça un complément adverbial]). [Exemple avec *pour*: Je VOUS ai cueilli cette rose. Exemple avec *chez, dans*: Je LUI trouve de grandes qualités.]

Note that it isn't what I made a reference to in a comment to Stéphane's answer, which is described so by Grevisse:

> La langue familière emploie d'une manière explétive le pronom de la première ou de la deuxième personne, pour exprimer l'intérêt que le locuteur prend à l'action ou pour solliciter l'interlocuteur de s'intéresser à l'action (c'est le *dativus ethicus* de la grammaire latine).